# Items in a listbox updating erratically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, itemssource

I have a simple list of strings which I want to be displayed in a listbox depending on if a checkbox is checked when a button is pressed. I have this logic in my button listener:

```
private void fileSavePerms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (CheckBox checkbox in checkboxList)
    {
        if (checkbox.IsChecked == true && !permissionList.Contains(checkbox.Name))
        {
            permissionList.Add(checkbox.Name);
        }

        else if (checkbox.IsChecked == false && permissionList.Contains(checkbox.Name))
        {
            permissionList.Remove(checkbox.Name);
        }
    }
    permListBox.ItemsSource = permissionList;
}
```

As far as I know, this is how you can do a very simple data-bind on button click. However the listbox updates for the first time as intended, but then will update with incorrect contents of the list I am trying to populate the box with. I can see no discernible pattern with the output.

Furthermore, after a while (a few button clicks), I will catch an exception saying "`an ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source`".

Am I setting up my binding incorrectly or assigning the `ItemsControl` at the incorrect time?

Update:

The XAML for the list box:

`<ListBox x:Name="permListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding permissionList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="28,512,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="442"/>`

Comment: Can you also share the corresponding XAML for this listbox?

Comment: @DaveS I have added the XAML for the listbox, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can bind only properties to a control. A field cannot be bound. So `permissionList` must be a property of the `DataContext` object you set to your `Window.DataContext` property.

If this is correctly set then you can create a new `List<string>` every time and then assign it to the property bound to the control. You do not have to assign it to the `ItemsSource` property of the control

Let's say your window's data context is set to the window itself.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<string> PermissionList
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(PermissionListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PermissionListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PermissionListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PermissionList",
            typeof(List<string>),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>())
        );

    private void fileSavePerms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // You create a new instance of List<string>
        var newPermissionList = new List<string>();

        // your foreach statement that fills this newPermissionList
        // ...

        // At the end you simply replace the property value with this new list
        PermissionList = newPermissionList;
    }
}
```

In the XAML file you will have this:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding PermissionList}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Margin="28,512,0,0"
    Height="36"
    Width="442"/>
```

Of course this solution can be improved.

- You may use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>` type so that you no longer have to create a new instance of `List<string>` every time but you can clear the list and add the new items in your `foreach` statement.
- You may use a ViewModel class (e.g. `MainViewModel`) that has this permission list and also implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and then you set an instance of this class to your WPF window's `DataContext` property.

Comment: Working perfectly thank you very much, looking into DependencyPropertys as well, seems a useful tool. Also worth mentioning that for your above solution, the XAML binding must be set to `{Binding PermissionList}`